# Flex: DateField how to get the value?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to use the DateField control.
I can set the current value using the selectedDate field.

Adobe says:

> Selecting the currently selected date in the control deselects it,
> sets the selectedDate property to null

so when user selects other date the selectedDate = null.

How do I can get the current selected value? I only saw in the debugger that DateField's text property contains the string with selected date? Do I need to parse it back?

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the problem. I was trying to format the date [like](http://flexonblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/tip-on-formatting-dates-with-the-datefield-control-in-flex/).

but I only implemented the label function and not the parse function and this caused the problem. When I implemented both everything became okay

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<mx:DateField selectedDate="{new Date()}"/>
```

this will give you today's date as selected date or you can do:

```
<mx:DateField selectedDate="{new Date(2010, 5, 7)}"/>
```

This will select the date 7th of June 2010

Month inputted is always -1 of the month you write: so december is 11, january is 0 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](http://www.cubicleman.com/2008/02/12/flex-datefield-and-formats/).

Simply set the `parseFunc` property of DateField as null. Did the trick for me..!!